# Cron with $_GET in Plesk

Tags: get, cron, plesk

I have to setup a cron in one of the latest versions of Plesk. The url for the cron is:
http://www.example.com/admin/cronmanager.php?route=cron/prods/all&key=1234
Via plesk dashboard, I can set script path and argument. Via folder button next to script path field, I can select the file on the server, so finding the correct path is easy (example.com/admin/cronmanager.php). The $_get variables are the problem. I tried to put them in the script path, but that didn’t work. I tried:

example.com/admin/cronmanager.php?route=cron/prods/all&key=1234

and

example.com/admin/cronmanager.php route=cron/prods/all key=1234

I also tried to put the $_get in the arguments like this:
route=cron/prods/all key=1234

Also didn’t work. Even Google wasn’t able to help me. In DirectAdmin this is no problem. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If I've right understand you set cron task 'Run a PHP script' via command line. There is no $_GET/$_POST variables in PHP command line, because there is no HTTP request to script.

Instead you can use 'Fetch a URL' task type and check var_dump($_GET):

[image: fetch url plesk cron]

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Don't know what the difference is between fetch a URL and run a PHP script, but run a URL works.
I used example.com/admin/cronmanager.php?route=cron/prods/all&key=1234 as URL without a problem.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @oleg-neumyvakin: In cron style you can use the shorthand "*/5" instead of "0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55".